# Deriving the Reparameterization Trick

Tags: expected-value, autoencoders, variational-bayes, generative-models

I am reading about the reparameterization trick from [here](https://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2018/04/29/reparameterization/).

It states

$\boldsymbol{\epsilon}\sim p(\boldsymbol{\epsilon})$, $\textbf{z}=g_\theta(\boldsymbol{\epsilon},\textbf{x})$, and
$$\mathbb{E}_{p_\theta(\textbf{z})}[f(\textbf{z}^{(i)})] = \mathbb{E}_{p(\boldsymbol{\epsilon})}[f(g_\theta(\boldsymbol{\epsilon},\textbf{x}^{(i)}))]$$

I am able to understand the steps that follow. How to derive the above equation? I understand it has to do with the change-of-variables, but I am not able to proceed beyond

$$\int_\textbf{z} f(\textbf{z}^{(i)}) p_\theta(\textbf{z}) d\textbf{z} = \int_\boldsymbol{\epsilon} f(g_\theta(\boldsymbol{\epsilon},\textbf{x}^{(i)})) \ p_\theta(g_\theta(\boldsymbol{\epsilon},\textbf{x})) \ |\det(J)| \ d\boldsymbol{\epsilon}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the change of variable formula directly gives ([see wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Function_of_random_variables_and_change_of_variables_in_the_probability_density_function)):

$$\int_z f(z^{(i)}) p_\theta(z) dz = \int_\epsilon f(g_\theta({\epsilon},{x}^{(i)})) \ p(\epsilon)d{\epsilon},$$

or in other terms,

$$\mathbb{E}_{p_\theta({z})}[f({z}^{(i)})] = \mathbb{E}_{p({\epsilon})}[f(g_\theta({\epsilon},{x}^{(i)}))].$$

The Jacobian relates to the way you would compute one density from the other, e.g., $p_\theta(z)=p(\epsilon)\left|\frac{dg_{\theta}^{-1}(z)}{dz}\right|$, however this is not what we are trying to achieve here.